# Proving a property of tame spectra

Tags: stable-homotopy

Let $U$ be a universe. Let $D$ be tame spectra, and let $f:E_1\rightarrow E_2$ be a map of spectra that is a spacewise homotopy equivalence. It is supposed to hold that $f^*: h\mathcal{S}U(D,E_1) \rightarrow  h\mathcal{S}U(D,E_2)$ is a bijection.

I can reduce this claim to proving that $f^*: h\mathcal{P}U(D,E_1) \rightarrow  h\mathcal{P}U(D,E_2)$ is a bijection, where $D$ is now a $\Sigma$-cofibrant prespectrum (i.e. the structure maps are cofibrations), but I have been so far unable to prove that this second map is a bijection.

As the structure maps are cofibrations, it would seem natural to use some lifting diagrams to patch the equivalences together, but against what fibrations?